# How to use LinearRegression in Spark based on text files

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I'm fairly new to programming with spark. I want to setup a linear regression model using spark based on log files with tabs as "column" separators. All tutorials, examples I found about it start off with something like this `JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, path).toJavaRDD();`
However, I have a bunch of log files I want to use. So what I tried so far is the following:

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    if(!new File("LogisticRegressionModel").exists())
    {
        buildTrainingModel();
    }
    else
    {
        testModel();
    }
}

private static void testModel()
{
    SparkSession sc = SparkSession.builder().master("local[2]").appName("LogisticRegressionTest").getOrCreate();
    Dataset<Row> dataSet = sc.read().option("delimiter", "-").option("header", "false").csv("EI/eyeliteidemo/TAP01.log");

    PipelineModel model = PipelineModel.load("LogisticRegressionModel");
    Dataset<Row> predictions = model.transform(dataSet);

}

private static void buildTrainingModel()
{
    SparkSession sc = SparkSession.builder().master("local[2]").appName("LogisticRegressionTest").getOrCreate();

    StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
            new StructField("label", DataTypes.DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty()),
            DataTypes.createStructField("features", DataTypes.StringType, false),
    });

    Dataset<Row> input = sc.read().option("delimiter", "-").option("header", "false").csv("foo/bar/Foo_*.log");
    input = input.drop("_c1", "_c3", "_c4");
    input = input.select(functions.concat(input.col("_c0"), input.col("_c2"), input.col("_c5")));
    input = input.withColumnRenamed("concat(_c0, _c2, _c5)", "features");
    input.show(30, false);
    Dataset<Row> dataSet = sc.createDataFrame(input.collectAsList(), schema);

    Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
            .setInputCol("features")
            .setOutputCol("rawTokens");
    StopWordsRemover swRemover = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol()).setOutputCol("cleanedTerms").setStopWords(readStopwords());
    HashingTF hashingTF = new HashingTF()
            .setNumFeatures(1000)
            .setInputCol(swRemover.getOutputCol())
            .setOutputCol("hashedTerms");
    IDF idf = new IDF().setInputCol(hashingTF.getOutputCol()).setOutputCol("featuresIDF");
    LogisticRegression lr = new LogisticRegression().setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(0.001);
    Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline()
            .setStages(new PipelineStage[] {tokenizer, swRemover, hashingTF, idf, lr});

    // Fit the pipeline to training documents.
    PipelineModel model = pipeline.fit(dataSet);
    try
    {
        model.save("LogisticRegressionModel");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String[] readStopwords()
{
    List<String> words = new ArrayList();
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(LogisticRegressionTest.class.getResource("stopwords_en.txt").toURI()))) {

        words = stream
                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] retWords = new String[words.size()];
    return words.toArray(retWords);
}
```

Unfortunately, I run into exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually StringType.
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictorParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Predictor.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.Classifier.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$ClassifierParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(Classifier.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ClassifierParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Classifier.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassifier.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$ProbabilisticClassifierParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassifierParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$LogisticRegressionParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(LogisticRegression.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(LogisticRegression.scala:184)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.validateAndTransformSchema(LogisticRegression.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.transformSchema(Predictor.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$transformSchema$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:184)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$transformSchema$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:184)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foldLeft(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:184)
at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.fit(Pipeline.scala:136)
at LogisticRegressionTest.buildTrainingModel(LogisticRegressionTest.java:92)
at LogisticRegressionTest.main(LogisticRegressionTest.java:40)
```

Now my problem/question is how to get this datatype issue right? Moreover, does my code make any sense to Spark experts in the first place?

Thanks!